# How to avoid duplicates in sql query across three joined tables

Tags: sql

I'm getting duplicates when I do two LEFT JOINs to get to the "event_name" in my example below. I get 112 cases with it set up this way. However, if I get rid of the 2 LEFT JOIN lines and run the query, I get the proper 100 records without duplicates. I tried DISTINCT with the code below, but I still get 112 with duplicates.

```
SELECT "cases"."id", "cases"."date", "cases"."name", "event"."event_name" 
FROM "cases"
LEFT JOIN "middle_table" ON "cases"."serial" = "middle_table"."m_serial"
LEFT JOIN "event" ON "middle_table"."e_serial" = "event"."ev_serial"
WHERE "cases"."date" BETWEEN '2012-12-11' AND '2012-12-13'
```

How can I specify that I only want the exact 100 cases from "cases", and that I don't want anything from the tables in the joins to produce any more rows?

Thanks!

Comment: How are tables related? 1:N from `cases` to `middle_table`? Could you tell us a bit about that?

Comment: could you provide some testdata? [sql-fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) is great for this.

Comment: In my case, I was getting duplicates due to joining with a one-to-many join. The only solution that I could find was to use sub-queries. A has many Bs. B has many Cs and many Ds. D has many Es and many Fs. I needed to fetch all Bs (that match a search string), while also aggregating all related Cs, Es, and Fs for each match. I used an outer join to get ABC, then used two sub-queries to aggregate DE and DF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to extend your ON clauses to include a condition so that for each entry in `cases` there is only one entry in `middle_table` that matches the condition and that for each entry in `middle_table` there is only one entry in `event`:

```
LEFT JOIN middle_table ON cases.serial = middle_table.m_serial AND some_condition
```

You can of course use DISTINCT. If that doesn't work it means that your results are all different in the fields `cases.id`, `cases.date`, `cases.name` and `event.event_name`. Examine the results and decide which of the entries you want to throw away and include that condition in your ON clause.

Comment: Hi AndreKR, so like I mentioned on JohnLBevan's post below: I don't care which child I drop since they are identical.
Would you be able to give a theoretical condition?

I just now understand that the Max function means "returns the largest value of the selected column".

Is there a simple way of just using that on an id field in one or both of the joined tables?

Comment: To do that you need to use one of these three techniques: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html But if they were really identical, DISTINCT would have filtered them away.

Comment: Note that above link is specific for MySQL but probably works with other systems, too. You should always state which DBMS you're using in your question anyway.

Comment: Looks like I'll need to do more digging to find out why DISTINCT isn't working then.

Comment: If it looks like distinct isn't working, find two rows with the same parent and compare the returned children. If they look identical start looking for white space (easy to spot if you concatenate quotes around the returned data, or return the lengths of any string fields instead of the data itself).

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking for that today.

Comment: In some cases maybe fields in aggregate functions like COUNT() is responsible so checking the GROUP BY clause may be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is you have multiple matches in the tables you're left joining with.  Effectively your code says:

```
select *
from parent
left outer join child on parent.id = child.parentId
```

If a parent has two children, you get both; so the parent appears twice.

If you want to only get the parent once you need to compromise; you can't have both children.  Either perform an aggregate function on columns from the child table and do a group by on columns from the parent table, or use `rownumber() over partition by (list,of,parent,columns order by list,of,child,columns) r` in an inner statement and `where r=1` in an outer statement, such as below:

```
select p.id, p.name, max(c.id), max(c.name) --nb: child id and name may come from different records
from parent p
left outer join child c on parent.id = child.parentId
group by p.id, p.name
```

or

```
select *
from 
(
    select p.id, p.name, c.id, c.name
    , rownumber() over (partition by p.id order by c.id desc) r
    from parent p
    left outer join child c on parent.id = child.parentId
) x
where x.r = 1
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, if the child data is exactly the same you can do this:

```
select p.id, p.name, c.name
from parent p
left outer join 
(
    select distinct c.parentId, c.name
    from child
) c on parent.id = child.parentId
```

or (if a few fields are different but you don't care which you get)

```
select p.id, p.name, c.id, c.name
from parent p
left outer join 
(
    select max(c.id) id, c.parentId, c.name
    from child
    group by c.parentId, c.name
) c on parent.id = child.parentId
```

Comment: ps. @AndreKR also makes a good suggestion; i.e. add conditional logic to the join to limit the results to a max of one child per parent.

Comment: Hi, I think I understand most of that. Yes: in my case, some of the parents have multiple children...but it's some kind of redundancy in the hospitals middle table or event table. Basically, both children of certain parents are exact duplicates: so I don't care which child I pick, because they are both the same.

Comment: In that case either of the above is good (second method is probably more efficient).  Alternatively you can filter out the duplicate children early on (though I suspect if a distinct statement isn't working, there are some differences in what's being returned at the child level, even if it's just the ids).

Answer (score 1):

The duplicates are the result of having multiple fields for "middle_table" and "event" for "cases".  You can limit the selections to the values that are unique by using the "GROUP BY" keyword (which is usually used for collating functions, such as COUNT and SUM), as follows:

```
SELECT "cases"."id", "cases"."date", "cases"."name", "event"."event_name" 
FROM "cases"
LEFT JOIN "middle_table" ON "cases"."serial" = "middle_table"."m_serial"
LEFT JOIN "event" ON "middle_table"."e_serial" = "event"."ev_serial"
GROUP BY  "cases"."id", "cases"."date", "cases"."name", "event"."event_name" 
WHERE "cases"."date" BETWEEN '2012-12-11' AND '2012-12-13'
```